# database corruption error while copying database monodroid

Tags: c#, android, database, eclipse, xamarin.android

I was developing android app on eclipse till now and now I'm using `Mono for Android`.

I am trying to copy the database from Assets folder, copy it onto the SD Card, then read data from it. I'm using the following code for the same. However I'm getting **database corruption error**.

After running the following code, empty database is getting created on SD card but the actual table is not getting copied.

Also how to **check SD card content in MonoDevelop**. I'm currently using eclipse for the same.

*As I'm just beginner to android development, any help appreciated.*

```
public class DbManager
{
    private Context ctx;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DatabaseHelper dataHelper;
    private String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/HelloM4A.HelloM4A/databases/";
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "CompanyMaster.db";
    private SQLiteCursor cur;
    private String[] b1;
    private int x;
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DbManager(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        dataHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    }

    private class DatabaseHelper : Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public DatabaseHelper AnyName
        { get; set; }
        Context myContext = null;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
            : base(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)
        {
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
        }

        public override void OnUpgrade(Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db, 
                                       int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            OnCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public bool checkDataBase()
    {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File(myPath);
        return f.Exists();
    }

    public void createDataBase()
    {
        openDB();
        try
        {
            Stream stream;
            string destPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "CompanyMaster.db");

            if (new Java.IO.File(destPath).Exists())
                using (stream = ctx.Assets.Open("CompanyMaster.db"))
                {
                    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH +
                                                                 DATABASE_NAME);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                    {
                        myOutput.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    if (mDb.IsOpen == true)
                        mDb.Close();
                    myOutput.Flush();
                    myOutput.Close();
                    stream.Close();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
    }

    public DbManager openDB()
    {
        try
        {
            mDb = dataHelper.WritableDatabase;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
        return this;
    }

    public String[] getSymbol()
    {
        try
        {
            cur = (SQLiteCursor)mDb.RawQuery("select symbol, company_name " + 
                                             "from Scrip", null);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        { }
        b1 = new String[2168];
        x = 0;
        if (cur.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do`
            {
                b1[x] = cur.GetString(cur.GetColumnIndex("symbol"));
                x++;
            }
            while (cur.MoveToNext());
        }
        cur.Close();
        return b1;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        mDb.Close();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

After various suggestions, I tried following code :

```
public void createDataBase()
{
    openDB();

    try    
    {           
        var dataFile = ctx.ApplicationContext
                          .GetDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME)
                          .AbsolutePath;
        Console.WriteLine("path="+
                          ctx.ApplicationContext
                             .GetDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME)
                             .AbsolutePath);

        // I get path=/data/data/HelloM4A.HelloM4A/databases/CompanyMaster.db 
        // which is correct.
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dataFile))
        {
            using (var input = ctx.Assets.Open(DATABASE_NAME))
            using (var output = System.IO.File.Create(dataFile))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }  
}

public DbManager openDB()
{
    try
    {
        mDb = dataHelper.WritableDatabase;
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return this;
}
```

Now the issue is if I don't use `openDB()` within `createDataBase()` , it gives `fileNotFoundException`.

and if I use `openDB()` within `createDataBase()`, it created empty DB and hence DB doesn't get copied and I get Blank DB as final ouput because of following condition `if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dataFile))`.

Since already empty DB is created it doesn't traverse inside if.

What can be done here?

Comment: Place the `openDB();` line after the `try` block.

Comment: I just removed it and it works !!

Comment: I used `var dataFile = Path.Combine(DATABASE_PATH, DATABASE_NAME);` where `private static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/HelloM4A.HelloM4A/databases/";` and 
        `private static String DATABASE_NAME = "CompanyMaster.db";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code to copy out of the assets folder to where I want it (you should be able to modify it to suit yourself):

```
const string dbName = "evolution.sqlite";
var dataDirectory = Path.Combine(ApplicationContext.FilesDir.AbsolutePath,
                                 "databases");
var dataFile = Path.Combine(dataDirectory, dbName);

if (!Directory.Exists(dataDirectory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dataDirectory);
}

if (!File.Exists(dataFile))
{
    using (var input = ApplicationContext.Assets.Open(dbName))
    using (var output = File.Create(dataFile))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I dynamically create the path as I am using an ORM instead of the DB helper classes.
You could use `dataDirectory = context.GetDatabasePath("").AbsolutePath();` instead.

You must do this before you use the `DatabaseHelper` as the database will also try and create the database. I do this in my `Activity.OnCreate(...)` method and then use the `DatabaseHelper` afterwards.

Thus, if my code was in a function called CopyDB(...) you use the method:

```
public DbManager openDB()
{
    CopyDB(...);

    try
    {
        mDb = dataHelper.WritableDatabase;
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: what is the 2nd parameter `"databases"` stands for? Is it the database name? If so it should be 'DBName` or `DBName.db`???

Comment: I'm so sorry for such stupid question. But `File` refers to `Java.IO.File` or `System.IO.File`???

Comment: The second param is the subfolder where you place your dbs. This is already in the path if you use `context.GetDatabasePath("")`. I have to add it because I am using `ApplicationContext.FilesDir.AbsolutePath`.

Comment: `!File.Exists(dataFile)` is the .NET method for checking to see if a file exists - it is ac class name. Exists is the method name. `File.Create(...)` is also a .NET method to create and open a file on the filesystem. - `System.IO.File`

Comment: If i use `dataDirectory = context.GetDatabasePath("").AbsolutePath();` it gives `StrinfOutOfBoundsException`. So I tried dataDirectory = context.GetDatabasePath("ABC").AbsolutePath(); and it works. In short , **it always requires sub-folder path**, but what if I want to copy the DB at data/data/Pkg_name/databases???

Comment: `ApplicationContext` is what I use to get a context from an `Activity` it is just the usual `Context` that is included in `View`s or various other classes. From which Type are you performing this method? (`Activity`, `View` or `DatabaseHelper`)?

Comment: Just use what I use. `ApplicationContext.FilesDir.AbsolutePath` returns `/data/data/Pkg_name` and then I Combine with `"databases"` to get the desired path.

Comment: But if i use `dataDirectory = context.GetDatabasePath("").AbsolutePath();` it gives StrinfOutOfBoundsException as `GetDatabasePath()` requires some Srting value I guess.

Comment: Use: `dataDirectory = Path.Combine(ApplicationContext.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, "databases")` - this will return the correct path.

Comment: `ApplicationContext.FilesDir.AbsolutePath` refers to `data/data/pkg/files`. So when I use `dataDirectory = Path.Combine(ApplicationContext.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, "databases")` , it stores the DB into `data/data/pkg/files/databases`.

Comment: option 2 : `dataDirectory = context.GetDatabasePath("ABC").AbsolutePath()` stores the DB at `data/data/pkg/databases/ABC`. Can you suggest me a way by which I can store the DB at `data/data/pkg/databases`

Comment: And mind you that `GetDatabasePath("")` doesn't work, some concrete name is required which will be the name of sub-folder created inside databases folder.

Comment: `GetDatabasePath(string name)` is actually supposed to do this: name : The name of the database for which you would like to get its path. So what you want to do is `GetDatabasePath("my_db_name.db").AbsolutePath`. This will give you the path to your db.

Comment: Place the `openDB();` after the `try` block